# Azure function in vs code using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am leaning azure function. I have created a basic azure function in visual-studio code using python runtime. I published the code and its working fine but when running locally. it is not able to identify the azure and pandas module. what should I do?

I have installed azure function core tool through MSI Installer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Import azure-functions could not be solved.

To avoid this type of warnings/errors:

1. Make sure Azure function core tools has been installed.
2. Include the required packages in `requirements.txt` in the project as shown below:

[image]

3. Activate [virtual-environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) before installing any packages in your project.

[image]

4. Install the required packages by running the commands:
   `pip install azure-functions`
   `pip install pandas`

[image]

```
                            (or)
```

Run the command **`pip install -r requirements.txt`** (the file which you have mentioned your packages:

[image]

**Project structure:**

***Before enabling the virtual environment and installing the packages:***

[image]

***After enabling the virtual environment and installing the packages:***

[image]

**Result:**

*Able to run the function:*

[image]

[image]